# query does not delete data from the db

Tags: php, mysql

this is my query

```
$db2=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("my_requests",$db2);

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN product ON details.user_id = product.user_id"); // find the city
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);// save record

        $id=$row['user_id'];
        echo "$id";


        $query1=mysql_query("DELETE * FROM details WHERE details.user_id=$id");
        $query2=mysql_query("DELETE * FROM product WHERE product.user_id=$id");
```

Here i have two tables products and detail ,user id is the primary key in details and made foreign key in product.

lets suppose i have two entries in the database with user_id =12 and another with user_id=11
 1. when i take the innerjoin of two tables and try to display the user_id's it shows only one user_id 12
 2. when i am trying to delete data using the user_id,it does not delete the data from the table.

sorry for the bad english

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: In your query try `Select product.user_id From...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SELECT` query, you have to specify tha table to get the `*` like `details.*` or `products.*`, becasue you're joinning two tables. In your case, it's the same result.

You also need to place `$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);` in a loop, to fetch each rows, then, you have a bad `DELETE` syntax  :

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id=$row['user_id'];
    echo "$id";

    $query1=mysql_query("DELETE FROM details WHERE details.user_id=$id");
    $query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM product WHERE product.user_id=$id");


}
```

Comment: I tried doing the same ,it deleted from the prduct table user_id=11 ,and did not delete rest of the entries

Comment: And your script is echoing more `$id` than deleted ?

Comment: no it is just displaying one id that is being deleted from the product table

Answer (score 7):

The [proper syntax of a `DELETE` query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) does not include `*`

```
DELETE FROM product WHERE product.user_id=$id
//^^^^^^^^^
```

If you do some basic error checking and debugging, the API will report a syntax error.

```
// This query has a syntax error and will return FALSE...
$query1 = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM details WHERE details.user_id=$id");
if (!$query1) {
  // On failure, see what your error was.
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

The above will report an error similar to:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM

Comment: @Shiven Don't use w3schools.  That is a SQL syntax reference, but not MySQL documentation.  MySQL doesn't permit a * there.  Check the MySQL docs directly.

Comment: @Shiven Furthermore, w3schools is found frequently to be out of date. It's notoriously unreliable.  Best to go always to the original source instead.